# Enthought EPD and Enthought Canopy, invoking specific ipython from each distribution

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, enthought, pythonpath

I have installed the new Enthought canopy on my local mac system which already had an installation of Enthough EPD. I made Canopy my default python installation and was wondering how I might be able to invoke the EPD ipython  instead of the default Canopy ipython as some of the modules installed into the EPD are not showing up in Canopy for obvious reasons and my scripts are broken as a result of being unable to import the required modules.

Comment: Why not install those modules into your new Python installation? It is not a good idea to share modules between Python versions.

Comment: Right but I just want to know how to do this because I plan to use these two distributions for two different purposes so I feel it would be more convenient to know how to invoke the specific version of ipython as needed. Is is as simple as prepending the path to ipython of EPD before the canopy ipython in the PATH env. variable?

Comment: I am fine with just using it per terminal session and ending up with canopy as the default ipython after the session closes because this is the behavior I prefer but I also want to have the option of switching to EPD whenever I would like to.

Comment: They are both executables as far as Windows is concerned, so placing one before the other in your PATH would let Windows pick one over the other, yes. You can always use one over the other by using a fully qualified path.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to make sure this was actually the case.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out that the solution to this problem is much simpler than manipulating the PATH env. variable which already has the path to my EPD enthought python distribution. When you select canopy to be the default python distribution on your MAC, it prepends the path to the canopy python interpreter to your PATH variable and adds the following lines into your .bash_profile :

```
# Added by Canopy installer on 2013-07-05
# VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT can be set to '' to make bashprompt show that Canopy is    
  active, otherwise 1
#uncomment the line below to make Canopy the default python distribution instead of EPD.
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source ~/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/activate
```

we are concerned only with the last line wherein the source command basically invokes the Canopy_64bit installation as a virtual env.

Solution : comment the last line with # , save the file and reopen the terminal (this change also takes care of the PATH env. variable and we don't need to mess around with that). The default python distribution is not canopy anymore. To revert back to canopy being the default, uncomment the same line.